# Можно ли приведенное предложение записать по-русски?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, заимствования

***Оверсайз не утрачивает актуальности, а аутфиты из денима продолжают штурмовать модный олимп.***

Как известно…

Я мог бы пред ученым светом

Здесь описать его наряд;

Конечно б это было смело,

Описывать мое же дело:

**Но панталоны, фрак, жилет,**

**Всех этих слов на русском нет...**

А можно это предложение записать по-русски, или уже тоже нет?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, все ещё можно, если сгладить жаргонизмы (в интересах обычного читателя) и отбросить пошлые штампы вроде "штурмования олимпа":

*По-прежнему успехом пользуется свободный покрой (oversize), а наряды из ткани деним все чаще оказываются среди предметов высокой моды.*

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, вот ваш вариант мне нравится, стиль хорошо выдержан. И не пропадайте, пожалуйста, вас здесь не хватает.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за добрые слова. Постараюсь вернуть себе привычку заходить сюда почаще. Летом отвлекся на починку усилителя старому другу и соседу - сосредоточился настолько, что пришлось уклониться от одной оживленной дискуссии. Сейчас свободного времени хватает, а в новейшие времена хочется защищать язык от "новоязмов".

Answer (score 0):

Оно по-русски записано (с использованием международных терминов), если не страдать снобизмом.
В качестве таблетки от снобизма процитирую фрагмент из интервью с Розенталем:

> *(Корр.) — Как вы относитесь к словам иностранного происхождения? Есть мнение, что мы должны стараться заменять их русскими эквивалентами: бульон
> называть прозрачным супом и т.п.*
>
> (Розенталь) — Я за чистоту русского языка, но это отнюдь не означает избавления от привычных нам заимствованных слов. Вот послушайте, что я сейчас скажу:
> я – студент филологического факультета петербуржского университета. Из
> всей фразы только одно слово русское – "я". Все остальные
> заимствованные, но тем не менее мы прекрасно понимаем смысл. А теперь
> мысленно попробуйте заменить все слова иностранного происхождения
> русскими эквивалентами. Сами запутаетесь, и количество слов в
> предложении увеличится примерно втрое.
>
> *— В русском языке много заимствований?*
>
> — Много, примерно 30%. Готовьтесь, через 5-6 лет их будет в два раза больше: "дилеры", "дистрибьютеры" прочно входят в обиход.
>
> *— А как же тогда быть с бессмертным "русский язык – богат и могуч"?*
>
> — Да не такой уж он и богатый по сравнению с другими языками. В его полном словаре, например, всего 200 тысяч слов, тогда как в немецком,
> включая, правда, диалекты – все 600 тысяч.

("Московский комсомолец", 21 мая 1994 г.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. я отнюдь не против заимствованных слов и не опасаюсь за русский язык. В конечном итоге контакт с иноязычной лексикой способствует его развитию, так как отбираются слова самые удачные и необходимые, а остальные отсеиваются. Но мне все-таки хотелось бы услышать эту фразу без трех не всем понятных слов.  Точно ли будет утрачены смысловые оттенки, которые име.ют эти слова, если их заменить  на русскую речь. Что они нам дают  в конечном итоге.

Comment: @Sharon оверсайз, аутфит и деним — это именно что термины, их вряд ли можно заменить, разве что описательным способом. Деним, к примеру, — тип ткани, как его иначе назвать?..

Comment: Не успела удалить запись, хотела продолжить. Ну а если дать общую оценку этой фразе, то я сказала бы так: немного «оверсайз».Перестарался, другими словами. В данном случае языковой вкус у фешн-блогера небезупречен. И еще забавно. Представьте, что вы этих слов не знаете вообще, ну вот впервые слышите. Какие у вас будут ассоциации по грамматике предложения? Какие-то «аутфиты» (вандалы, вероятно) штурмуют модные магазины (весьма актуальная тема). Деним? В следующей фразе он называет эту ткань джинсовкой.

Comment: @Sharon ну, у них, фэшн-блогеров, своя атмосфера. Я всё-таки склонен считать это профессиональным жаргоном. Если я веду теологический диспут, то тоже зачастую пользуюсь терминами, это нормально.

Comment: Ну если жаргон, то да. Но мне-то хотелось узнать, насколько такие слова свойственны современной разговорной речи. Аутфит, например. Насколько нам необходимо это слово, каковы прогнозы на будущее конкретно для него? (Это я представила себя в роли журналиста.) Впрочем, благодарю вас за ответы.